# Is there a selenium API call to check if somethingIsSelected in a MultiSelectField?

Tags: java, firefox, junit, selenium

I am aware that there is a selenium API (isSomethingSelected) used to see if a value is selected in single-select dropdown. Is there an equivalent for multiselect?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried storeSelectedIndexes(), storeSelectedLabels(), or storeSelectedValues()?

As far as I've seen there is no way to directly check the selection of a multi-select element, but someone could have written an extension.

Comment: where are these apis from? they are definitely not part the seleniumRC api.